# How to prevent _ga parameter from being added to download links

Tags: google-analytics

My company just started using cross-domain Google Analytics, which means that a _ga parameter is being added to all our links. Unfortunately this is breaking one of our downloads. The link is being turned into, for example:

> filename.ext?_ga=1.222222222.333333333.4444444444

This downloads fine in most browsers, with the resulting file being named filename.ext, however, in Internet Explorer, the resulting file is named filename.4444444444 as it is ignoring everything between the first period and the last. The browser should be parsing out parameters, but is not. Since I can't make changes to Internet Explorer code, how can I stop my site from adding the _ga parameter to certain links?

Comment: There is very little context in the question  - I assume you use the autolink plugin, and the problem occurs if you link to a download on the respective other domain ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff Sorry about that. To be honest, that was all the context I was given. My team is responsible for developing the website but it was some analyst from another team that added the Google Analytics and broke everything. I don't have access to our Google Analytics account so I don't know what settings we have. I suppose what I was looking for was some data-* attribute or class or something that can be put on a link to prevent the _ga parameter.